# installing windows on external HD

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I have the problem of installing Windows via bootcamp onto an external Hard drive, I previously installed windows via bootcamp with no problems, Now when I try to do it via online guides to install windows via bootcamp onto my external USB 3 Hard drive, On the select language screen I don't get any function from the track pad or keyboard.

Ive tried to connect USB2 keyboards and mice and it still doesn't work.

If I am to install Windows onto the Hard drive via a Windows machine, and then install bootcamp drivers onto the Hard drive, Will I be able to boot onto the hard drive on my mac?

Comment: Please add your Mac model, which install method you use (USB/DVD) and the Windows version. Also link your "online guides".

Comment: 15" macbook pro retina, the top model. I used the USB version of the install with windows 7 x64 Ultimate SP1.

the guide i used was 

http://bleeptobleep.blogspot.fr/2013/02/mac-install-windows-7-or-8-on-external.html

I followed the guide and everything went smoothly up until the windows logo started swirling around and then a quick flash of bsod and then reboot.

Answer (score -1):

I'have same problem and I found this solution. I hope useful...

http://twocanoes.com/winclone/support/migrate-windows-8-to-an-external-drive-using-winclone-4.3-and-later